# Convert dynamically all columns of df to numpy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to convert to numpy array all my columns of a df, so that I could later refer to variable to manipulate the array.

This doesn't work

```
DictDF = {}
for Column in MainDF.columns:
    DictDF[Column] = MainDF.Column.values
```

`MainDF.Column.to_numpy()` doesn't allow either

I get an error : `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Column'`

Therefore, how could I do to dynamically convert those columns to numpy array ?

Comment: `MainDF[Column]`?

Comment: That was it ! Thank you ! Any way to do it in 1 line without the for loop ?

Comment: Have a look at [df.to_dict('series')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html)

Comment: If you don't mind `lists`, try `df.to_dict(orient='list')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dictionary comprehension to do it in one line:
DictDF= {i: MainDF[i].values for i in MainDF.columns}